# Angularjs: How to refresh page when clicking through pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pagination bar, which clicks through each repeating section, the next section of resources appears once the pagination is clicked without the page reloading.

However when I click the pagination to go from one section to another, I would like the entire page to reload so I start at the top of the page.

Here is how the link is setup now:

```
<a pagination-link="true" key="_page_60_resources_repeatingsection1" rel="next" href="?_page_60_resources_repeatingsection1=6" page="6">6</a>

{_pagination(resources.order_by("id", "asc").filter("status", _equals("Active")).filter("search_hint", _contains("{filter.search}")).filter("category_ref", _contains("{filter.category}")).filter("city", _contains("{filter.area}")).filter("language", _contains("{filter.language}")), "_page_50_resources_repeatingsection1", per_page: 3, route: reload, page: response._page_50_resources_repeatingsection1)}
```

Comment: Are you are building a SPA? Why you need to refresh the page?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is a request from upper management.